# What is the recommended way to setup integration test in sbt after the deprecation of custom configs

Tags: scala, sbt

I have just stumble into this:

https://eed3si9n.com/sbt-drop-custom-config/

Specifically:

> **what about IntegrationTest?**
>
> IntegrationTest should be removed. It doesn’t add anything useful besides the fact that it hangs off a subproject.

So what is the recommended way to run Integration test? Should I create a subproject containing those tests? How can then be run separately from the other tests?

Comment: maybe, I would create another module for the integration test, adding the core modules as project dependencies. And maybe another sbt task. But, I think that another module is a good option.

Comment: As the [release notes mention](https://eed3si9n.com/sbt-1.9.0-beta#IntegrationTest) the recommended workaround is to create a custom module.

Comment: As a trivia: AFAIK not much people used It test configuration in sbt. Why? Because (again AFAIK) IntellIJ team stated somewhere that this approach of custom test configurations is incompatible with their model and they never gonna support it. So many teams using IntelliJ already migrated to using separate module for their it tests, just so that they could run it from their IDE without manually writing commands in a terminal. I run sbt in my terminal emulator, so it never affected me, but I saw such discussions (rewrite it test to test but in a separate module) in companies that I worked for.

Comment: As alternative, I am considering leverage munit tags to selectively run one or another: https://scalameta.org/munit/docs/filtering.html#include-and-exclude-tests-based-on-tags

I find that extra projects will add extra noise so I am looking to this alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
lazy val IntegrationTest = (project in file("integration"))
  .dependsOn(root % "provided -> provided;compile -> compile;test -> test; runtime -> runtime")
  .settings(
    publish / skip := true,
    // extra test dependencies
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.org" %% "integration_test_dep" % "1.0.0" % Test,
    ),
  )

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(name := "my-application")
```

It specifies a separate module in folder `integration` and to run the integration tests, you can type:

```
sbt IntegrationTest/test
```

Comment: That may be the *recommended* way, but as of nearly 2024, to maintain the compatibility with IntelliJ IDEA test integration UI, just add `.settings(Defaults.itSettings, ...`